# Calling Mysql SP from ASP creates error

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic

When I tried calling a MySql stored proc from classic ASP, I get this error:

OUT or INOUT argument 5 for routine spAddContactUsEmail is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Here is the SP (which I can call successfully from Mysql workbench):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spAddContactUsEmail`(
    In vcName varchar(50),
    In vcPhone varchar(50),
    In vcEmail varchar(50),
    In txtComments text,
    Out intNewID int
)
BEGIN

    Insert Into contact_us (`Name`, Phone, Email, Comments, DateCreated) 
    Values (vcName, vcPhone, vcEmail, txtComments, now());

    Set intNewID = Last_Insert_ID();

END
```

Here is the ASP code:

```
Dim con
Dim cmd

Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open "connection string" 

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "spAddContactUsEmail"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("vcName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "John Doe")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("vcPhone", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "333-4444")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("vcEmail", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "test@yahoo.com")
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("txtComments", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len("hey"), "hey")

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("intNewID", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)

cmd.Execute
```

The error occurs on the cmd.Execute line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include error message details returned by `Execute` method.

Comment: Error msg is: -2147467259, [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.7.17-log]OUT or INOUT argument 5 for routine spAddContactUsEmail is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Comment: Seems that you need to set output parameter using `adParamOutput` here: `cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("intNewID", adInteger,  adParamOutput, adParamReturnValue)`.

Comment: I made the change you mentioned but still got the same error.

Comment: Which version of MySQL ODBC driver being used? Some earlier drivers may don't have support to `OUT` parameters, in this case you need to use `cmd.CommandText = "CALL spAddContactUsEmail (@vcName, ..., @intNewID)"` then execute `SELECT @intNewID` using same connection (just changing command text).

Answer (score 0):

Change adParamReturnValue to adParamOutput:

```
<%
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("intNewID", adInteger, adParamOutput, 4)
%>
```